# Audio Issues with Mobile iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, audio

I'm working on a breathing app using React. My app works fine on all desktop browsers and android devices, but not on mobile iOS, in which case, the audio for the main breathing function doesn't play at all.

Here's the weird part. It will play audio for the other sections of the app. There is an intro, and a tutorial, both of which play their own respective audio just as they should. But the main breathe function does not.

Here is an example of the Intro:

```
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './styles';
import { ButtonBar, Header } from 'components';
import IntroContent from './Intro-content';
import { createAudio, playAudio } from 'dha-assets';
import intro_female from '../../assets/audio/Female/intro_female.mp3';
import intro_male from '../../assets/audio/Male/intro_male.mp3';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Logo from '../../assets/images/Logo.svg';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

interface State {
  gender: string;
}

createAudio('intro_female', intro_female);
createAudio('intro_male', intro_male);

const playFemaleIntro = () => {
  playAudio('intro_female');
};

const playMaleIntro = () => {
  playAudio('intro_male');
};

const Intro: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const gender = useSelector<State>((state) => state.gender);
  const [paragraphs] = useState(IntroContent.intro.paragraphs);
  const [displayParagraph, setDisplayParagraph] = useState('');
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  if (gender === 'female') {
    playFemaleIntro();
  } else {
    playMaleIntro();
  }

  const timeoutDelays = [0, 5000, 3700, 5700, 4900, 7500, 9000, 6700, 6700, 8000];

  useEffect(() => {
    const changeParagraph = () => {
      setDisplayParagraph(paragraphs[index]);
      setIndex(index + 1);
    };
    setTimeout(changeParagraph, timeoutDelays[index]);
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {index >= 10 ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : null}
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.img}>
          <img src={Logo} alt="TB Logo" />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.paragraph}>
          <p>{displayParagraph}</p>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.buttonBar}>
          <ButtonBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Intro;
```

and here is the Breathe function:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './styles';
import { ButtonBar, Header } from 'components';
import BreatheCircles from './BreatheCircles';

const Breathe: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.circles}>
          <BreatheCircles />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.buttonBar}>
          <ButtonBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Breathe;
```

BreatheCircles uses setInterval to rotate through the different circles in order, and they are all pretty much set up the same. Here is one of the circles:

```
import React, { Component, FC } from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './styles';
import Counter from 'components/Counter/Counter';
import { State } from 'containers/Tutorial/Tutorial';
import { playAudio } from 'dha-assets';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const playFemaleInhale = () => {
  playAudio('inhale_female');
}
const playMaleInhale = () => {
  playAudio('inhale_male');
}

const InCircle: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const gender = useSelector<State>((state) => state.gender);

  if (gender === 'female') {
    playFemaleInhale();
  } else if (gender === 'male') {
    playMaleInhale();
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.circleBreatheIn} />
      <div className={classes.text}>
        Inhale
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

// This is a wrapper class for the FC above. The animaations work better with the class.
class BreatheInCircle extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <InCircle />
        <div style={{ color: '#000' }}>
          <Counter />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default BreatheInCircle;
```

Here is what I have thought so far, iOS autoplay disabled. But if this was the case, the intro and tutorial also wouldn't play either. So I don't think this can be.

And for those of you wondering about dha-assets, it maintains a map of your audio files as they are created. You can then play, pause, and stop, from that single map (That's how the audio files are called to be played in the breathe cirles). I did try creating the audio files in the circles themselves, but that didn't make a difference.

Please let me know if I need to be more clear. I'd be glad to answer any questions that you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I am answering my own question, but I did solve this problem, kind of. I ended up combining all the audio files into one file, one for the female voice and one one for the male, and played it directly in the Breathe file.

I am still looking for a better solution. And if anyone finds it, please post it.

I don't think the way I am doing it now is the most efficient way to do it, and I would like my code to be as efficient and clean as possible.

Here is the code for the final breathe function:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { useStyles } from './styles';
import { ButtonBar, Header } from 'components';
import BreatheCircles from './BreatheCircles';
import { audioFiles, createAudio } from 'dha-assets';
import { State } from 'containers/Tutorial/Tutorial';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import breathe_female from '../../assets/audio/Female/breathe_female.mp3';
import breathe_male from '../../assets/audio/Male/breathe_male.mp3';

createAudio('breathe_female', breathe_female);
createAudio('breathe_male', breathe_male);

const Breathe: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const gender = useSelector<State>((state) => state.gender);

  if (gender !== 'mute') {
    audioFiles[`breathe_${gender}`].play();
    audioFiles[`breathe_${gender}`].loop = true;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.circles}>
          <BreatheCircles />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.buttonBar}>
          <ButtonBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Breathe;
```